# Python 2.7. Iterating list not working

Tags: list, python-2.7, iterator, collatz

Just starting with Python and doing some challenges, this one on Collatz numbers.
I am stuck at the start however, where the range that I am passing to the `collatz` method is not iterating over the given range.

What am I missing here?

```
def collatz(number):
    for i in number:
        if i % 2:
            return i // 2
        else:
            return 3 * (i + 1)


try:
    print(collatz(range(0,10)))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Zero Division")
except TypeError:
    print "Type Error"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for i in range(0,10):
        print(collatz(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

### algorithm

- If the number is even, divide it by two.
- If the number is odd, triple it and add one.

### code

```
def f(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    else:
        return 3 * n + 1

def a(i, n):
    if i == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return f(a(i - 1, n))

def collatz(n):
    i = 0
    c = 0
    out = []

    while c != 1:
        c = a(i, n)
        out.append(c)
        i += 1
    return out

print(collatz(6))
```

### output

```
[6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the 'return' statement is causing your function to exit on the first iteration, thus preventing further iterations from occurring.

Long answer:
Here's a breakdown of how your code is running.

- collatz(number) receives a list [0,1,...10]
- A loop is created for [0,1,...10] starting from 0
- 1st, start with i = 0
- 0 % 2 evals to 0, which is False, which means we skip to the else statement
- We return 3 * (0 + 1), which evaluates to 3.
- We finish the call to collatz(number)

The correct approach is answered in some other folks' posts.